# Get ID of selected button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Currently I have a list of options (Which can be selected through clicking the button next to the option.)

The following is the JavaScript code when I click the button.

```
    $('.step3').click(function() {
        var os_name = $('.step3').attr('id');
        alert(os_name);
        var os_update;
        os_update ="nothing so far";
        if (os_name == "os_c_5_64") {
        os_update = "centos-5-x86_64";
        }
        if (os_name == "os_c_6_64") {
        os_update = "centos-6-x86_64";
        }
        if (os_name == "os_c_65_64") {
        os_update = "centos-6.5-x86_64";
        }

        alert(os_update);
        $('#vmos').val(os_update).change();
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is get the ID of the actual selected button - Not directly from the class.

```
                       <tr class="appliance">
                            <td class="distro"><img src="<?=$this->tpl_asset_path;?>images/centos.jpg"></td>
                            <td class="description">Centos 5 64bit</td>
                            <td class="author">Linux distribution</td>
                            <td class="text-right"> <li class="step3" id="os_c_5_64" style="list-style: none;"><a class="btn btn-primary create" data-toggle="tab" href="#step3">Select</a></li></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="appliance">
                            <td class="distro"><img src="<?=$this->tpl_asset_path;?>images/centos.png"></td>
                            <td class="description">Centos 6 64bit</td>
                            <td class="author">Linux distribution</td>
                            <td class="text-right"> <li class="step3" id="os_c_6_64" style="list-style: none;"><a class="btn btn-primary create" data-toggle="tab" href="#step3">Select</a></li></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="appliance">
                            <td class="distro"><img src="<?=$this->tpl_asset_path;?>images/centos.png"></td>
                            <td class="description">Centos 6.5 64bit</td>
                            <td class="author">Linux distribution</td>
                            <td class="text-right"> <li class="step3" id="os_c_65_64" style="list-style: none;"><a class="btn btn-primary create" data-toggle="tab" href="#step3">Select</a></li></td>
                        </tr>
```

What's the best way to find the ID of the button I just clicked.

I'm currently using: `var os_name = $('.step3').attr('id');`
Which simply isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Within a jQuery event handler the `this` keyword will refer to the element which raised the event.

As such, you can use either `this.id` or `$(this).prop('id');`. Note however that the former is by far the better practice.

Comment: _please_ don't recommend `$(this).prop('id')` !!

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.id` instead or the jQuery version `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: no, just `this.id` - the jQuery method is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Within your jQuery event handler (or in handlers registered with `addEventListener`) you can just use `this` to access the clicked element and therefore the below to get its ID:

```
var os_name = this.id;
```

It's completely portable and maximally efficient.

Please do *not* be tempted to use `$(this).attr('id')`.  A `console.trace` for that is shown below:

```
f.extend.propjquery.min.js:2
f.extend.attrjquery.min.js:2
e.extend.accessjquery.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.attr
```

This shows that just the `.attr` call alone requires a further three function calls internally, and that's even before you account for the overhead of calling `$(this)`.

Using `$(this).attr('id')` replaces a trivial property look up with *at least five* function calls!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery as well? Try:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: IMHO there's no way this deserves an upvote.  Technically it works, but it's a symptom of sloppy coding when `this.id` works perfectly well without needing (at least) two function calls.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript you can generally get an Element by Id using:

document.getElementById("myButton")

if you have assigned it an Id. If you have you might also be able to modify your code a little and use something like this:

```
<script>
  function getValue()
  {
    var x=document.getElementById("myHeader");
    alert(x.innerHTML);
  }
</script>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) is some more details.

Comment: this doesn't even remotely answer the question.